# SSRS Report with Bar and Line

Tags: reporting-services, charts, series

I need to translate this DataSet result into the following chart.
Been trying all sorts of combinations for value, group, series but I can't figure it out!  Can someone assist please!  Thanks in advance

*SQL Data Set*
[image: SQL Dataset]

*Chart I need to create*
[image: Chart I need to create]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but to get chart data I would UNPIVOT your data and create two columns in your dataset. Below is some sample code that will turn your illustrated dataset into something easier for the chart to handle.

```
-- CREATE A Month NUmber table
-- Create this as a physical table, I'm doing this as a Table variable for this exmaple only
-- CREATE TABLE dbo.Months (Month_Name varchar(3), Month_Number int)
DECLARE @Month TABLE(Month_Name varchar(3), Month_Number int)

INSERT INTO @Month VALUES
('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr', 4), ('May', 5), ('Jun', 6), 
('Jul', 7), ('Aug', 8), ('Sep', 9), ('Oct', 10), ('Nov', 11), ('Dec', 12)

-- CREATE and populate dummy table
DECLARE @t table (FranchiseNumber int, Report_Year int, Jan int, Feb int, Mar int, Apr int, May int, Jun int, Jul int, Aug int, Sep int, Oct int, Nov int, Dec int)

INSERT INTO @t Values 
(103332, 2016, 578,591,616,611,611,577, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(103332, 2017, 343,332,324,310,309, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

DECLARE @d TABLE(FranchiseNumber int, Month_Name varchar(3), Previous_Year int, Current_Year int)

-- unpivot, create prev and current year columns and add a month number to help sort the Axis
INSERT INTO @d
select 
    FranchiseNumber
        , Month_Name
        --, DATEPART(MM, Month_Name + ' 01 1999') AS Month_Number  -- REMOVED
        , SUM(CASE Report_Year WHEN 2016 THEN Month_Value ELSE NULL END) AS Previous_Year
        , SUM(CASE Report_Year WHEN 2017 THEN Month_Value ELSE NULL END) AS Current_Year
    from 
        @t p
    UNPIVOT
        (Month_Value FOR 
            Month_Name IN (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
        ) as unPiv
    GROUP BY FranchiseNumber, Month_Name, DATEPART(MM, Month_Name + ' 01 1999') 

SELECT d.FranchiseNumber, m.Month_Name, m.Month_Number, d.Previous_Year, d.Current_Year
    FROM @Month m
    LEFT JOIN @d d ON m.Month_Name = d.Month_Name
```

This gives us the following output.
[image]

The chart design looks like this.

[image]

All I did was create a line chart drag the current and previous year columns into the values area, click the Previous_Year drop-down in the values area and change the chart type to column.

After that I right-clicked on the horizontal axis and sorted by Month_Number

**update:** You will probably have to right-click the horizontal axis, select properties and change the interval to 1 or not all month labels may be displayed.

It's not perfect but it should get you close.

To produce the table underneath, add a new dataset, pointing to your original data and add a new tablix that points to it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's working great for me thanks but I have one issue with the data.  I need 12 months returned in the resultset 1-12 and nulls if no data so my chart always has 12 months displayed.

Comment: I've updated the code. Basically I've added a months table. It's useful to have physical dates tables and things like this in your database for jobs like this. Essentially I'm taking most of the UNPIVOT we had before and LEFT JOINing it to a table of months and month numbers so we get a full set of data for the chart.